# Configure Azure Terraform provider to only allow SSH access to my current IP address

Tags: terraform, azure

After following this quick start guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/quick-create-terraform, running `lastb` on the provisioned host shows login attempts from many IP addresses.

The included security rule

```
  security_rule {
    name                       = "SSH"
    priority                   = 1001
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "22"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
```

is too permissive. Ideally, it would restrict the source_address to my IP address.

What's the best way to restrict ssh access? Some ideas:

1. Statically configure my current IP address in `main.tf`
2. Dynamically configure the security rule using my current IP address at provision time
3. Run a post-provisioning script to allow only my current IP address
4. Something else

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This provisions the host with a more restrictive ssh rule.

Add this to `variables.tf`:

```
variable "source_address_prefix" {
  type        = string
  description = "Source IP address allowed to make ssh connections."
}
```

Change the security rule to this:

```
  security_rule {
    name                       = "ssh"
    priority                   = 1001
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "22"
    source_address_prefix      = var.source_address_prefix
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
```

Set this environment variable (use the actual public IP address you use to connect):

```
export TF_VAR_source_address_prefix=192.168.1.1
```

Provision:

```
terraform apply
```

Verify no more connection attempts to the newly provisioned Azure VM.